# Books for learning PID control?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, pid-control

I am aiming to program a quadcopter flight controller as a personal project.
To be able to do this I understand one of the  fundamentals is a PID control system . So my question is does anyone have any recommendations for books to read or will google be good enough?

I have found the following books , has anyone read these?:
"Advanced PID  control" - [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Advanced-PID-Control-Karl-Astrom/dp/1556179421/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1538160392&sr=1-4&keywords=pid+control)
or ,
"PID Control: New Identification and Design Methods" - [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/PID-Control-Identification-Design-Methods/dp/1849968977/ref=sr_1_14?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1538160392&sr=1-14&keywords=pid+control)

Comment: If you want to learn the *fundamentals* of any topic, don't start with books containing "Advanced" in the title. "New Identification and Design Methods" could be a collection of new research into the subject - and most methods published in research papers never become "mainstream" techniques, simply because they don't work very well except for the specialized problem the researchers were working on.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @niels nielsen  mentions the topic is very broad and successful implementation and design require additional techniques not necessarily directly associated with control design. Depending on your specific application this might include dynamic modeling, system identification, model validation and updating, etc.

There are numerous books that deal with PID control and, given the above, it should be clear that it is impossible to provide an exhaustive list of references. I have not used the books you mention and although their table of contents looks decent their applicability will depend on your particular application. Some alternative references are mentioned below.

To get a quick overview of what a PID controller actually does the [Wikipedia page on this subject](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller?wprov=sfti1) is actually quite decent. However, I would not consider this sufficient information for any serious implementation.

For SISO control systems I’ve used both “Feedback Control of Dynamic Systems” by Franklin and “Feedback Systems: An Introduction for Scientists and Engineers” by Astrom and Murray. The former is somewhat outdated but covers the basics well and also includes some material on dynamic modeling. The latter is more up to date, covers some more advanced materials and is also available [online](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/Second_Edition).

For control of MIMO systems I personally like “Multivariable Feedback Control” by Skogestadt. However, if you decide to go into this direction, be prepared for the mathematical approach that is inherent to understanding the design and analysis of MIMO control systems.

Another good reference, which approaches PID control from an implementation point of view, is “Applied Control Theory for Embedded Systems” by Tim Wescott. I think this is SISO only but it does discuss PID tuning based on measured transfer functions and how to measure these transfer functions. If you are looking for rigorous mathematical detail this is not the book for you.

Answer (score 0):

The engineering problem of designing from first principles an optimal PID control system is a topic about which entire textbooks have been written and is the subject of semester-long introductory courses at the upper-division university level. Google will most assuredly not be enough. If it were, mechanical engineering students would not have to spend four years learning the basics.

To even begin the process of designing a control system requires you first to furnish a dynamical model of the system you wish to control, which is a discipline all unto itself. Unless your model is accurate, your subsequent efforts to devise a suitable control system for it are doomed.